# Sequelize model is pointing to a the wrong model when querying

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have two models, `Customer` and `SignupStatus`, however it seems that if I query CustomerModel.findAll(), the query generated is querying the SignupStatus table instead.

As a result, I am not able to query anything properly.

Another thing is I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Sequelize' of undefined`. I found some answers only that suggest something wrong with the associations. However, I can't seem to find anything wrong in my code that leads to the model being wrongly referenced...

Does anyone have any ideas ?

EDIT:

It seems that even though my import path is `import CustomerModel from '../db/models/customers.model';`, the actual Model imported is the SignupStatusModel.

Which is very strange because the path for SignupStatus is `'../db/models/signupStatus.model'`

Here are my files:

**Customer.model.ts**

```
class Customer extends Model {
  public id!: number;

  public prefix: string;

  public firstName: string;

  public lastName: string;

  public email: string;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;

  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

  public static initModel(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
    Customer.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        firstName: {
          type: new DataTypes.STRING(255),
        },
        lastName: {
          type: new DataTypes.STRING(255),
        },
        email: {
          type: new DataTypes.STRING(255),
          allowNull: false,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'customers',
      }
    );
  }

  public static initAssociation(): void {
    this.hasOne(SignupStatus);
  }
}
```

**SignupStatus.model.ts**

```
class SignupStatus extends Model {
  public id!: number;

  public customerId: number;

  public companyId: number;

  public emailVerified: boolean;

  public emailVerificationCompletionDate: Date;

  public customerProfileCompleted: string;

  public customerProfileCompletionDate: Date;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;

  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

  public static initModel(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
    Customer.init(
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        customerId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        companyId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        emailVerified: {
          type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
          defaultValue: false,
        },
        emailVerificationCompletionDate: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
        customerProfileCompleted: {
          type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
          defaultValue: false,
        },
        customerProfileCompletionDate: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'signupStatus',
      }
    );
  }

  public static initAssociation(): void {
    this.belongsTo(Customer);
  }
}
```

**index.model.ts**

```
export const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME,
  process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: true,
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
      idle: 10000,
      acquire: 30000,
    },
    dialectOptions: {
      // same as host string above
      socketPath: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    },
  }
);

export const initModels = async (sequelizeInst: Sequelize) => {
  console.info('Initializing sequelize models...');
  await Customer.initModel(sequelizeInst);
  await SignUpStatus.initModel(sequelizeInst);
};

export const initAssociation = async () => {
  console.info('Initializing sequelize associations...');
  await Customer.initAssociation();
  await SignUpStatus.initAssociation();
};
```

Comment: In your `class SignupStatus` you are calling `Customer.init`, is that correct?

Comment: @AndreaPollini oh my god. I can't even look at myself right now. Thanks for pointing this out.